# Login component displays the HTML of homepage

Tags: angular

My *app.component.html* looks like this:

```html
<h1>Homepage</h1>
<app-footer></app-footer>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have another component called `login`. If I go to http://localhost:4200/login, it shows me the HTML of the `login` component but I see the HTML of *app.component.html* (in this case `<h1>Homepage</h1>`) as well. I don't want that code in my login component. If I delete `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, it won't show me the HTML of login component anymore. How can I fix this?

Comment: That's how your code is supposed to work ,  the router outlet injects the code of the login component to  `app.component.html` if you need to separate the  home component create a separate `homeComponent` and route for the same so that you can load it into app.component.html when needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to add another component like homePageComponent:

homePageComponent html:

```
<h1>Homepage</h1>
```

and in your routing module add a new route

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: homePageComponent }
]
```

and in the app.component.html you can remove your header tag.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the Home page because you have the HTML code on the app.component.ts . There are two ways to fix it, add a boolean variable and enable/disable based on the variable using ngIf.

Add a route in your app.module.ts to have a path for your home component as a separate page.

```
const routes: Routes = [    
  { path: '', component: homePageComponent }
]
```

2nd way is most recommended.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1>Homepage</h1>
<app-footer></app-footer>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here Anything you write in the `app.component.html` will be shown in every component the routed.

**Problem 2**
If you remove the the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` then non of your router link will work.

**Possible solution**
Whenever you login, set the item in local storage like `isLoggedIn : true` and by default assign it value to `isLoggedIn : false`, therefore whenever you open the login page, if the user is already logged in i.e., `isLoggedIn: true` then `HELLO WORLD`  will be shown And if `isLoggedIn : false` then `HELLO WORLD` will not be shown. 

Just do it as the code below , 

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    // isLoggedin : any;    
    isLoggedin = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isLoggedin"));
    constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) {  
        // this.userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("called");
        if(!this.isLoggedin){
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }else{
            console.log("called 2nd time");
            console.log(this.isLoggedin);
            this.isLoggedin = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isLoggedin"));

        }
     }


}
```

**.html**

```
<h1 *ngIf="isLoggedin">Homepage</h1>
<app-footer></app-footer>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

If you have any query , share your code in stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

Angular creates SPA (Single Page Application) which by default has a root module 
i.e. your app module which has app component which act as a root component.

This root component connects a component hierarchy with the page document object 
model (DOM). Therefore root component html(template), css(styling), logic(ts) will be applied across the whole SPA.

For loading your other component not the root when application is bootstrapped, include a route in app routing

```
const routes: Routes = [    
  { path: '', component: otherComponent }
] //when base url is entered load otherComponent
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common app sctructure issue. You can solve this, with a child route. Restructure your router whit a sub `<router-outlet>` where you can dispart your shared and main components from your auth components. Like in my example: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y9bxfy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).